# How to read an image name with PIL

Tags: python, python-2.7, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm going to open some image:

image = Image.open(path)

And now I want to store their names in a variable so I can use them later, how can I do this?

The idea is to create a loop:

```
for i in range (0,20) # I have 20 images
```

And from there we can create a condition:

```
if variable_containing_image_name == 'something*.jpg'

else:
```

P.S.: I'm using:

```
from PIL import Image
import glob, os
import numpy as np
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet will take all files in from the directory specified by the path variable and put them in the images list so long as they end with '.jpg'. You can then iterate over the images list and do whatever you like with them.

```
import os
from PIL import Image

path = 'the path to your image directory'
# Store the image file names in a list as long as they are jpgs
images = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if os.path.splitext(f)[-1] == '.jpg']

for image in images:
    Image.open(image)
    # Do whatever you need to do with the image
```

Answer (score 1):

Not totally clear on the surrounding code but surely splitting the path string and taking the final element?
Like:

```
filename = path.split("/")[len(path.split("/")-1]
filenames.append(filename)
```